# need fix function time

Tags: php, function, time

Hello everyone I have a problem here and I'm trying to find a solution

The problem is that is calculated inputs are taken out as a time in some cases, the result will be very high, for example, 900: 00:00 hours do not result appears as expected, but 838: 59: 59 any show that this is the highest end of time can be calculated I want solution to this is that even if the calculation time of 900: 0:00 or 1000: 00:00 hours I hope I have brought information sorry for my bad English

this is my cosde

```
<?php

class WebHelper
{

public function sendMail( $to,     $from, $subject, $message )
   {
    $subject = sprintf( "=?utf-8? B?".base64_encode( $subject )."?=" );
    $headers = sprintf( "To: %s   <%s>\nFrom: %s\nMIME-Version:   1.0\nContent-type: text/html;   charset=utf-8", $to, $to, $from );
    return mail( $to, $subject,   $message, $headers );
   }

 public function getDomain( )
 {
    $surl =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVE R['REQUEST_URI'];
    $surl = preg_replace(   "/^(www\\.)/", "", $surl );
    $arr = explode( "/", $surl );
    $count = sizeof( $arr ) - 1;
    if ( 0 < $count )
    {
        $surl = "";
        $i = 0;
        while ( $i < $count )
        {
            $surl .= $arr[$i]."/";
            ++$i;
          }
        }
      return strtolower( $surl );
  }

public function getBaseUrl( )
{
    return ( WebHelper::isssl( ) ?   "https://" : "http://" ).$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].strrev( strstr( strrev( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ), "/" ) );
}

public function isSSL( )
{
    return !( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) || preg_match( "/^(|off|false|disabled)\$/i", $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) );
}

public function getClientIP( )
{
    $ip = "";
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) )
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    else if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) )
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) )
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

public function secondsToString( $seconds )
{
    $seconds = intval( $seconds );
    $h = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
    $m = floor( $seconds % 3600 / 60 );
    $s = floor( $seconds % 60 );
    if ( $h < 0 || $m < 0 || $s < 0 )
    {
        return "0:00:00<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return showManual(7,0);\">?</a>";
    }
    return $h.":".( $m < 10 ? "0" : "" ).$m.":".( $s < 10 ? "0" : "" ).$s;
}

public function getDistance( $lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $radius )
{
    $angle = $radius / 180;
    $lat1 /= $angle;
    $lon1 /= $angle;
    $lat2 /= $angle;
    $lon2 /= $angle;
    return rad2deg( acos( sin( deg2rad( $lat1 ) )  sin( deg2rad( $lat2 ) ) + cos( deg2rad( $lat1 ) )  cos( deg2rad( $lat2 ) )  cos( deg2rad( $lon1 - $lon2 ) ) ) )  $angle;
}

}

 ?>
```

Comment: *function code have error* And which error does your function have? Also what do you mean with *unlimited time* ? Please make a example: e.g. current input, current output and expected output

Comment: read my example please

Comment: Can you share the whole class/file? Because the shared code-snipped is syntactically wrong.

Comment: i cannot edit i try now i cannot show edit button

Comment: I still dont understand what you are trying to do... maybe you can type your question in your native language and then google translate it?

Comment: ok 2 min man and back chek this questions